# Add Plugin with defined GlobalErrorhandler in Vue

Tags: javascript, vue.js, plugins

I wrote and added a globalerrorhandler (Vue.config.errorHandler, window.onerror, ...)

I followed the "Writing Plugin in vue" on the vue website.

But i get following error and i dont know why:
'MyPlugin' is not defined

I created a pluginFolder within my project. Within this folder i added another folder "GlobalErrorHandler". Within this folder i added  "MyPlugin.js".

App.vue:

```
import MyPlugin from './plugins/GlobalErrorHandler'
Vue.use(MyPlugin);
```

Code in MyPlugin.js:

```
MyPlugin.install = function (Vue){
    Vue.config.errorHandler = function(err, info) {
      
        const toSend = {
          "error": err,
          "info": info
        }
      
        const jsonString = JSON.stringify(toSend);
        const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
              
              xhr.open("POST", "http://localhost:8090/api/auth/event");
              xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
              xhr.send(jsonString);
              console.log(jsonString);
        
        };

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `MyPlugin` object has to exist first before adding the `install` property to it:

```js
const MyPlugin = {};  // Create the object
```

and *MyPlugin.js* needs to export the object or it can't be imported:

```
export default MyPlugin;  // export for importing
```

Putting it together:

```js
const MyPlugin = {};
MyPlugin.install = function (Vue){
  Vue.config.errorHandler = function(err, info) {

    const toSend = {
      "error": err,
      "info": info
    }

    const jsonString = JSON.stringify(toSend);
    const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

    xhr.open("POST", "http://localhost:8090/api/auth/event");
    xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
    xhr.send(jsonString);
    console.log(jsonString);

  };
}
export default MyPlugin;
```